# Is omitting the auxiliary verb that is needed to form the perfect tense correct in this example from a FAZ-article?

Tags: verb, style, perfect-tense

Here is the context:

> So hat er nun den israelischen Ministerpräsidenten Benjamin Netanyahu davon überzeugt, auf dem Tempelberg die Metalldetektoren wieder abzubauen und andere Sicherheitsvorkehrungen zu treffen. Im Februar **er** Präsident Trump klargemacht, dass die Verlegung der amerkanischen Botschaft in Israel von Tel Aviv nach Jerusalem zu einer nicht kontrollierbaren Destabilisierung in der Region führen würde.

This is the first time I encounter such a case. I thought it should be either:

> ... zu treffen, und im Februar Präsident Trump klargemacht,...

(no need for a subject, nor for a verb, and without starting a new sentence), or:

> ... zu treffen. Im Februar hat er Präsident Trump klargemacht,...

Is this simply a mistake? If not, when is such a style appropriate/correct?

Answer (score 8):

No! Omitting the auxiliary verb is not correct here. This is an error. The correct version would be:

> Im Februar **hat** er Präsident Trump klargemacht, ...

Comment: Past perfect ("hatte") would probably be more correct as "So hat er nun...überzeugt" is perfect and "klargemacht" clearly happened and was finished before.

Answer (score 6):

It is just an error. Probably it should have been “hatte er”.